# incompatible type when using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, incompatibletypeerror

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct contact
{
    my_string name;
    my_string email;
    int age;
} contact;

typedef struct contact_array
{
    int size;
    contact *data;
} contact_array;

void print_contact(contact *to_print)
{
    printf("%s (%s) age %i\n", to_print->name.str, 
    to_print->email.str, to_print->age);
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    contact_array contacts = { 0, NULL };
    for(i = 0; i < contacts.size; i++)
    {
        print_contact(contacts.data[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'print_contact'
note: expected 'struct contact *' but argument is of type 'contact'.
```

I have declared the `my_string` structure elsewhere, and I don't think that that is the problem. I am just unsure as to how to get the print procedure call and the procedure declaration to have matching types.

Comment: change void print_contact(contact *to_print) to void print_contact(contact to_print). You are passing contacts.data[i] which is not an address but the data block itself

Comment: @Lewis, You don't need to pass-by-reference if you are just going to print the values. Simply change `void print_contact(contact *to_print)` to `void print_contact(contact to_print)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your compiler is telling you to pass a pointer type to the `print_contact` function, like so:

```
print_contact(&contacts.data[i]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it was a combination of this solution, plus me trying a different library for user input that seems to be able to work with the change you recommended.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
void print_contact(contact *to_print)
```

to

```
void print_contact(contact to_print)
```

or pass it as

```
print_contact(&contacts.data[i]);
```

You are passing `contacts.data[i]` which is not an address but the data block itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
    print_contact(contacts.data[i]);
```

should be

```
    print_contact(&contacts.data[i]);
```

This is because `contacts.data` is of type `struct contact *`, and `contacts.data[i]` is of type `struct contact`. Therefore, you can either pass `contacts.data + i` or `&contacts.data[i]` . Just a notational difference.

Note that: `my_string` is not defined in the code and the standard headers does not include it.

Comment: OP has already mentioned that `my_string` is defined elsewhere.

Comment: Yes it is mentioned, but there is no header file on the code which seems to contain it, therefore I have mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a reference:

```
    print_contact(&contacts.data[i]);
```