# Incompatible type for argument for struct array

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, struct

I have a structure defined as

```
struct Bod{
  int x, y;
};
```

Then I have a function

```
void add(struct Bod* s) {
    h[++nh] = s;
}
```

And in next function, I tried to pass array into the previous function, which gives me error **Incompatible type for argument 1 of function add()**

```
void bfs(struct Bod* body, int start_index){

    struct Bod* v;
    add(body[start_index]);
    ...
}
```

And in main, I have created this array of struct like this

```
struct Bod body[m*n];
```

What did I miss?

Comment: `body[start_index]` is of type `struct Bod` amd not `struct Bod*`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30591049/incompatible-type-when-using-pointers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `body[start_index]` gives you **one** element of `body` at index `start_index`, you end up passing in that single element to `add()`.

If you want to pass in the array itself, you just need to pass in `body` as-is:

```
add(body);
```

Or, to pass in the array starting at a given index:

```
add(&body[start_index]);
```

Comment: Thanks, `&body[index]` helped

Comment: Or `add(body + start_index);`